# Plotly bar plot colored by week?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to make a what is a simple plot in excel but can't figure out how to do it in plotly.
[image]
I've tried:

```
px.bar(df, x=['A','B','D','E'], color='date')
```

but it gives a key error.

Comment: You can use a histogram with two traces. See first example under Styled histograms here: https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#styled-histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways that you can make this happen. I'm not sure how you brought the data into Python.

If you used a dictionary or a Pandas data frame, either of the two methods I'll show will work. The first uses Plotly Express, since that's what it appears you tried to use. The second method uses Plotly as a Pandas backend.

The Plotly Express Method

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

d = ["8-5-2022", "8-12-2022"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"dt": d, "A": [0, 20], "B": [0, 20], "D": [80, 40], "E": [20, 0]})
df2 = df1.melt(id_vars = 'dt', value_vars = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'])
print(df2)
"""
          dt variable  value
0   8-5-2022        A      0
1  8-12-2022        A     20
2   8-5-2022        B      0
3  8-12-2022        B     20
4   8-5-2022        D     80
5  8-12-2022        D     40
6   8-5-2022        E     20
7  8-12-2022        E      0
"""
fig = px.bar(df2, x = 'variable', y = 'value', color = 'dt')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Using Plotly as a Pandas Backend

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

d = ["8-5-2022", "8-12-2022"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"dt": d, "A": [0, 20], "B": [0, 20], "D": [80, 40], "E": [20, 0]})

df2 = df1.melt(id_vars = 'dt', value_vars = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'])
print(df2)
"""
          dt variable  value
0   8-5-2022        A      0
1  8-12-2022        A     20
2   8-5-2022        B      0
3  8-12-2022        B     20
4   8-5-2022        D     80
5  8-12-2022        D     40
6   8-5-2022        E     20
7  8-12-2022        E      0
"""
fig = df2.plot.bar(x = "variable", y = "value", color = "dt")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the shape of the dataframe is equal to whats shown in the excel, I guess if I make it match your format it will work

Comment: I originally made the data frame as it appears in the spreadsheet. I melted it into the data frame I used for the plot.

Comment: Data is generally easier to work with when it's in long format the way @Kat shows here

Answer (score 0):

Data is generally easier to work with when it's in long format the way @Kat showed, but if you wanted to keep your data frame as is, you could try this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['8/5/2022', '8/12/2022'],
           'A':[0,20],
           'B':[0,20],
           'D':[80,40],
           'E':[20,0]})

print(df)
        date   A   B   D   E
0   8/5/2022   0   0  80  20
1  8/12/2022  20  20  40   0

fig = go.Figure()

for row in range(len(df)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.columns[1:],
                 y=df.iloc[row][1:].tolist(),
                 name=df.iloc[row][0])
              )
fig.show()
```

[image: Fig]